# Scala to connect in HIVE via JDBC - HDP

Tags: scala, jdbc, hive

i'm trying to connect in HIVE (in sandbox of Hortonworks) and i'm receving the message below:

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2://sandbox.hortonworks.com:10000/default

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>                                                      
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>                       
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>                  
        <version>${spark.version}</version>                       
        <scope>provided</scope>                                   
    </dependency>                                                     
    <dependency>                                                      
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>                       
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>                   
        <version>${spark.version}</version>                       
        <scope>provided</scope>                                   
    </dependency>                                                     
    <dependency>                                                      
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>                       
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>                  
        <version>${spark.version}</version>                       
        <scope>provided</scope>                                   
    </dependency>                                                     
</dependencies>
```

Code:

```
   // **** SetMaster is Local only to test *****                                  
    // Set context                                                                
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("process").setMaster("local")      
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)                                          
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)                                         

    // Set HDFS                                                                   
    System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hdfs")                                
    val hdfsconf = SparkHadoopUtil.get.newConfiguration(sc.getConf)               
    hdfsconf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020")           
    val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hdfsconf)                                           

    // Set Hive Connector                                                         
    val url = "jdbc:hive2://sandbox.hortonworks.com:10000/default"                
    val user = "username"                                                         
    val password = "password"                                                     

    hiveContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> url,                     
    "user" -> user,                                                               
    "password" -> password,                                                       
    "dbtable" -> "tablename")).load()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Hive JDBC driver in your application classpath:

```
<dependency>                                                      
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>                       
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>                  
    <version>1.2.1</version>                       
    <scope>provided</scope>                                   
</dependency>
```

Also, specify driver explicitly in options:

```
"driver" -> "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
```

However, it's better to skip JDBC and use native Spark integration with Hive, since it make possible to use Hive metastore. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: Good deal, I'm trying to use it, any  ideas how to connect in sandobox from  my local machine, I mean that I'm working in a local machine and I need to connect in sandobox, if I just open a context it suppose that i'm working in sandbox.

Comment: I suggest to start from Hive config  [hive-site.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/resources/data/conf/hive-site.xml), assuming you have Hadoop configuration already in place. Also, make sure that your version of Spark built with Hive support (default binary is not)